# Select from multiple tables without a join?

Tags: mysql

What is the easiest way to select data from two tables and rather than join them, have them appear as separate rows. Both tables have similar or matching fields and I want to run some aggregate function on them such as avg all the rows that occurred in the same month, from both tables.

for example I have two tables, one that is shows transactions from one system and another with transactions from a different system. Is there a way to grab all the transactions from both tables as separate rows? if table 1 had twenty records and table 2 have thirty records, I'd like there to be 50 rows on the return.

Answer (score 76):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM (
    SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT f1,f2,f3 FROM table2
)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: the answer is under one column

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal: I don't understand you comment, sorry... what do you mean?

Comment: when i use union all results comes under one column

Comment: my situation is different

Comment: @AdarshMPallickal: if your situation is different, then post a question showing your situation and your needs...

Comment: sorry @Marco i don't have the permission to ask question.

Comment: You may want to use UNION ALL, in case the two tables have identical data column-wise. The OP seems to want ALL records from both tables to show.

Comment: @banncee: Good point. The `UNION` operation will collapse *all* duplicate rows in the resultset. Those duplicate rows could be coming from two different SELECTs, but they could also be from just one of the SELECTs. The `UNION` operation doesn't make a distinction. It collapses *all* of the duplicate rows in the set. The **`UNION ALL`** set operator avoids that (sometimes very expensive) operation of identifying and collapsing duplicates.

Comment: UNION ALL is faster, but doesn't filter out duplicates.

Answer (score 56):

You could try this notattion:

```
SELECT * from table1,table2
```

More complicated one :

```
SELECT table1.field1,table1.field2, table2.field3,table2.field8 from table1,table2 where table1.field2 = something and table2.field3 = somethingelse
```

Such queries are usually called "implicit JOINs" and [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins) asks how both compare. In some cases implicit query execution planning is identical to explicit JOINs.

Comment: If table1 is empty then he won't be able to get results from table2

Comment: Downvoted, because the comment by @user846226 is true. This answer is useful in general to know, but doesn't answer the question correctly.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, I think comma separated tables isn't ANSI-92 compatible.

Comment: Is there a particular name for this notation?

Comment: i believe it's called implicit join

Comment: This command "works", but there is no data in the results, only the columns...
I assume I'll need to use "join" to retrieve the results.

Comment: @ryvantage writing the above query is just shorthand for a CROSS JOIN: `SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2`

Answer (score 48):

The `UNION ALL` operator may be what you are looking for.

With this operator, you can concatenate the resultsets from multiple queries together, preserving all of the rows from each. Note that a `UNION` operator (without the `ALL` keyword) will eliminate any "duplicate" rows which exist in the resultset. The `UNION ALL` operator preserves all of the rows from each query (and will likely perform better since it doesn't have the overhead of performing the duplicate check and removal operation).

The number of columns and data type of each column must match in each of the queries. If one of the queries has more columns than the other, we sometimes include dummy expressions in the other query to make the columns and datatypes "match". Often, it's helpful to include an expression (an extra column) in the SELECT list of each query that returns a literal, to reveal which of the queries was the "source" of the row.

```
SELECT 'q1' AS source, a, b, c, d FROM t1 WHERE ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'q2', t2.fee, t2.fi, t2.fo, 'fum' FROM t2 JOIN t3 ON ...
UNION ALL
SELECT 'q3', '1', '2', buckle, my_shoe FROM t4
```

You can wrap a query like this in a set of parenthesis, and use it as an inline view (or "derived table", in MySQL lingo), so that you can perform aggregate operations on all of the rows.

```
SELECT t.a
     , SUM(t.b)
     , AVG(t.c)
  FROM (
         SELECT 'q1' AS source, a, b, c, d FROM t1
          UNION ALL
         SELECT 'q2', t2.fee, t2.fi, t2.fo, 'fum' FROM t2
       ) t
 GROUP BY t.a
 ORDER BY t.a
```

Answer (score 16):

If your question was this -- Select ename, dname FROM emp, dept without using joins..

Then, I would do this...

```
SELECT ename, (SELECT dname 
FROM dept
WHERE dept.deptno=emp.deptno)dname
FROM EMP
```

Output:

```
ENAME      DNAME
---------- --------------
SMITH      RESEARCH
ALLEN      SALES
WARD       SALES
JONES      RESEARCH
MARTIN     SALES
BLAKE      SALES
CLARK      ACCOUNTING
SCOTT      RESEARCH
KING       ACCOUNTING
TURNER     SALES
ADAMS      RESEARCH

ENAME      DNAME
---------- --------------
JAMES      SALES
FORD       RESEARCH
MILLER     ACCOUNTING

14 rows selected.
```

Comment: This is the only answer that actually worked for me as I'm currently trying to migrate a database to Azure and it contains old style join syntax (which is not allowed in Azure). Most joins are simple to change the syntax of, however 

SELECT [tab1].[col1], [tab2].[col1] FROM [tab1],[tab2] 

isn't easy when they don't share a column to join on.

Comment: it's a join. You've just used older syntax.

Comment: worked for me since I didn't have anything to join on, I just needed external info and didn't want a second query for one datapoint.

Comment: May i know what this method is called as i know this method is much faster then join or union

Comment: @insoftservice, I believe this is a correlated subquery. More info at [DoFactory.com](https://www.dofactory.com/sql/subquery).

I would caution you on large queries, however. I believe performance can suffer when the subquery is run against a large working set.

Comment: Thanks @Troy . But many claims that by using this method performance of query increases instead of traditional join method. is it true do you have some more information or some links for it. It would be really helpful

Answer (score 11):

You should try this

```
 SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM t1,t2
```

Comment: This is an implicit join.  As indicated by the similar answer 7 years prior to yours, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It's not appearing the expecting result

Answer (score 3):

SELECT * from table1
UNION
SELECT * FROM table2

Answer (score 2):

Union will fetch data by row not column,So If your are like me who is looking for fetching column  data from two different table with no relation and without join.
In my case I am fetching state name and country name by id. Instead of writing two query you can do this way.

```
select 
   (
   select s.state_name from state s where s.state_id=3
   ) statename,
   (
   select c.description from country c where c.id=5
   ) countryname
   from dual;
```

where dual is a dummy table with single column--anything just require table to view

Answer (score 0):

select 'test', (select name from employee where id=1) as name, (select name from address where id=2) as address ;

Answer (score -1):

In this case we are assuming that we have two tables:
`SMPPMsgLog`and `SMSService` with common column `serviceid`:

```
SELECT sp.SMS,ss.CMD 
FROM vas.SMPPMsgLog AS sp,vas.SMSService AS ss 
WHERE sp.serviceid=5431 
AND ss.ServiceID = 5431 
AND Receiver ="232700000" 
AND date(TimeStamp) <='2013-08-07' 
AND date(TimeStamp) >='2013-08-06' \G;
```

Comment: The comma operator between the two table references specifies a join operation.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this works always for me

```
query="SELECT * from tableX,tableY,table8";
```

Comment: Have you read the question, about separate rows ?