# Querying across multiple tables with identical schemas

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to run the same query over multiple tables in my Postgres database, that all have the same schema.

This question: [Select from multiple tables without a join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095109/select-from-multiple-tables-without-a-join) 
shows that this is possible, however they are hard-coding the set of tables.

I have another query that returns the five specific tables I would like my main query to run on. How can I go about using the result of this with the UNION approach?

In short, I want my query to see the five specific tables (determined by the outcome of another query) as one large table when it runs the query.

I understand that in many cases similar to my scenario you'd simply just want to merge the tables. I can not do this.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this that may satisfy your constraints is using [table inheritance](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-inherit.html).  In short, you will need to create a parent table with the same schema, and for each child you want to query you must `ALTER that_table INHERIT parent_table`.  Any queries against the parent table will query all of the child tables.  If you need to query different tables in different circumstances, I think the best way would be to add a column named `type` or some such, and query only certain values of that table.

Comment: I do have a parent table with the same schema that is empty, as I was thinking along these lines.In your `ALTER that_table INHERIT parent_table` code, how would you insert the result of the query that determines which sub tables to run on?

Comment: As I mentioned above, I wouldn't query a list of tables per say, but I would add a ``type`` column to each table that was check constrained to a single value.  Then I would query only certain types at a time, which would effectively query certain tables.  I would not recommend querying the pg internal tables (pg_class etc.) to get the table names, because they are likely to be subject to change when you upgrade your postgres version.