# get all record without join in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i have two tables table1 and table2, table1 in 10 filed available and tbale2 in 6 filed available.but no any relation between them.

i want to get all record from both table.

Comment: You don't wanna use JOIN at all? You can use it as "SELECT table1.*,table2.* FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON 1=1";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select from multiple tables without a join?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12095109/select-from-multiple-tables-without-a-join)

Answer (score 1):

Use cross join

```
Select t.*,t1.* from table t cross join table1 t1
```

If you want all the records in the same table use the above query it will join and give **m*n** rows where m and n are number of rows in the tables

You can use **union all** if you want all the results added **m+n** number of results

```
Select * from table
Union all
Select * from table1
```

You need to specify the columns if you need specific columns from both tables. Or if you have different number of columns in the tables

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least some common columns, you can union them together.  For example:

**Table1**

Name  Description Quantity Price

**Table2**

Name  Description OrderDate Blah BlahBlah

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT Name, Description FROM Table1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Name, Description FROM Table2
```

That would give you a result set with 2 columns (Name, Description, OrderDate) that is made up of rows from both Table1 and Table2